# Xcode 7 breakpoint doesn't stopped in objective-c code

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, breakpoints, xcode7

The issue is that instead of stopping in the beginning of objC code, it stops somewhere in the "middle" in assembly code. I have default xcode and project preferences, all optimizations are disabled, showing dissasembly disabled. It starts after updating on Xcode 7, I have the same bug with the same project on different machines. What it can be? May be some problems with user preferences, e. g. xcuserdata files, etc.?[image]

Comment: It means your  app is crashing before it's going to your function

Comment: It's not a crush, app works normally if I disable breakpoints. And the issue doesn't appear always, only with some breakpoints.

Comment: watch on left panel after you see this crash. it will give info on which line it stopped

Comment: can you make a screenshot of your breakpoint navigator?

Comment: @RobertoFerraz https://www.dropbox.com/s/95lmfkfxi9z3g4e/Screenshot%202015-09-25%2013.28.20.png?dl=0 As temp solution, I'm just moving breakpoints to +/- 1 line and it works normally

Comment: @RobertoFerraz breakpoints navigator https://www.dropbox.com/s/oe1f8vw1px9e5eg/Screenshot%202015-09-25%2013.31.02.png?dl=0

Comment: @SashaKid take a look in the answer and let me know..